# NoReverseMatch at /tinku/update

Tags: python, django

**Reverse for 'update_student' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/update$']**

it is showing error above please tell if anyone know about this how to resolve this

**urls.py**

```
path('',views.index,name="home"),
path('<slug:name>/update',views.student_update,name="update_student"),
path('delete/<slug:name>',views.student_delete,name="delete_student")
```

**student_update.html**

```
<div class=" row d-flex justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-6 box-shadow">
    <form action="{% url 'update_student' %}" method="POST" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{updateform|crispy}}

    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control">update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**views.py:-**

```
def student_update(request,name):
instance=get_object_or_404(Student,name=name) 
print(instance) 
form=StudentForm(request.POST,instance=instance)
print(form)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('home')

return render(request,'webapp/student_update.html',{'updateform':form})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
```

from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator,MinValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Student(models.Model):
    gender=(
        ('M','male'),
        ('F','female')
        )

```
name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
age=models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(18),MaxValueValidator(50)])
sex=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=gender)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
```

from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator,MinValueValidator
from webapp.models import Student

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields=['name','age','sex']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `{% url 'update_student' %}` in your template (the form action), which is causing the error because the `update_student` pattern requires a `name` parameter.

So you either need to change it to `{% url 'update_student' name=form.instance.name %}` but since your form is posting to the same url as the one it's rendered on, it's easier to just remove the `action` attribute completely.